# How solve python requests error: "Max retries exceeded with url"

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the follow code:

```
res = requests.get(url)
```

I use multi-thread method that will have the follow error:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='bjtest.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/data?method=check&test=123 (Caused by : [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)

I have used the follow method, but it still have the error:

```
s = requests.session()
s.keep_alive = False
```

OR

```
res = requests.get(url, headers={'Connection': 'close'})
```

So, I should how do it?

BTW, the `url` is OK, but it only can be visited internal, so the `url` have no problem. Thanks!

Comment: is bjtest.com reachable ?

Comment: @DuyNguyen Yes, but it only visit internal.

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar case, hopefully it can save some time to you:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8001): Max retries exceeded with url: /enroll/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10f96ecc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))`

The problem was actually silly... the localhost was down at port 8001! Restarting the server solved it.

Answer (score 4):

you run your script on Mac? I also meet similar problem, you can execute ulimit -n to check how many files you can handle in a time.

you can use below to enlarge the configuration.

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (the number you reset,resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
```

hoping can help you.

[my blog which associated with your problem](http://blog.csdn.net/schunlee/article/details/54898382)

[image]

Comment: `ulimit -n` result is `65536`

Answer (score 3):

The error message (which is admittedly a little confusing) actually means that `requests` failed to connect to your requested URL at all.

In this case that's because your `url` is http://bjtest.com/rest/data?method=check&test=123, which isn't a real website.

It has nothing to do with the format you made the request in. Fix your `url` and it should (presumably) work for you.